# Git ssh url to a specific folder

Tags: git, teamcity

I am setting up my build in TeamCity and it needs an ssh path to the repository.  Usually when I do this, I have one repository per autobuild.  But in my current case, I need to have several autobuilds pulling from the same project (I am building container images).

This is the example ssh I have:

> ssh://git@ssh.code.mydomain.net/myproject/container-images.git

But the actual path I want to check out all the files under is:

> code.mydomain.net/myproject/container-images/base-build/aspdotnetcore_3.1.10.debian_10.6.build

Is there a way to make an SSH path to that folder only?  (So I get that checked out specifically and only.)

Answer (score 1):

No, Git does not allow repository URLs to specify a particular folder for any protocol.  You cannot clone just a particular folder, since commits always refer to the top-level tree.  Git must have those objects in order to keep the objects you care about reachable.

You have a couple of options:

- Check out the entire repository.
- Check the repository out somewhere else and create a symlink to the folder you want.
- Clone the repository with the `--sparse` flag and update the patterns to check out only the files you want (which you can do with `git sparse-checkout` in recent versions of Git).